# How to create a simple calculator using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am able to do it with text-box and the dropdownlist but what i need is to  create a calculator using a text but i am  not able to enter the button values to the text-box

Here is my index.html

```
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.3" data-semver="3.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="calculatorCtrl">

 <div class="offset4 span6 well">
 <label>Enter a value :</label>
 <input ng-model="firstNumber" type="text"> <br/><br>


 <label>Another Value:</label>
 <input ng-model="secondNumber" type="text"> <br/><br>

 <label>Operator:</label>
 <select ng-model="selectedOperator"
 ng-options="operator for operator in operators"></select> 
 <br><br>
            <button ng-model="btn1" class="numberbutton" value="1" ng-click='updateOutput(1)'>1</button>
            <button name="btn2" class="numberbutton" value="2" ng-click='updateOutput(2)'>2</button>
            <button name="btn3" class="numberbutton" value="3" ng-click='updateOutput(3)'>3</button>
             <button name="btn0" class="numberbutton" value="0" ng-click='updateOutput(0)'>0</button>
            <br>

            <button name="btnPlus" class="operationbutton" ng-click='add()'>+</button>
             <button name="btnMinus" class="operationbutton" ng-click='subtract()'>-</button>
             <button name="btnEquals" class="operationbutton" ng-click='calculate()'>=</button>
 <button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button> <br><br>

 Result: {{result}}
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my here is my js file:

script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('calculatorCtrl',function ($scope) {  


$scope.operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
$scope.selectedOperator = $scope.operators[0];



 $scope.updateOutput = function (btn) {
    if ($scope.output == "0" || $scope.newNumber) {
        $scope.output = btn;
        $scope.newNumber = false;
    } else {
        $scope.output += String(btn);
    }
    $scope.pendingValue = toNumber($scope.output);
};

$scope.calculate = function() {
    var A = parseInt($scope.firstNumber);
    var B = parseInt($scope.secondNumber);
    var C = 0;

    switch ($scope.selectedOperator) {
        case '+':
            C = A + B;
            break;
        case '-':
            C = A - B;
            break;
        case '*':
            C = A * B;
            break;
        case '/':
            C = A / B;
            break;                
    }

    $scope.result = C;
}; });
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/hkjsDJEUTJMFOkdMmgNM?p=preview

Comment: A few suggested tips for posting, so as to reduce edit work: avoid excessive bold in your questions; don't add "please help" and similar, as it is often sounds like begging; don't use txtspk like "plz" and similar, as it reduces readability (and Stack Overflow is not a chatroom). Code should be formatted using code formatting, not quoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it angular style

Controller :

// Code goes here

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('calculatorCtrl',function ($scope) {  

 $scope.txt = '';
 $scope.numbers = [];
 $scope.operators = [];

 $scope.calculate = function() {
    var sum = 0;

    while($scope.operators.length > 0){
      var right = $scope.numbers.pop();
      if(isNaN(right)){
        right = 0;
      }
      var left = $scope.numbers.pop();
      if(isNaN(left)){
        left = 0;
      }

      var op = $scope.operators.pop();
      sum += calc(left,right,op);

    }

    $scope.result = sum;
    $scope.numbers = [];
    $scope.operations = [];
    $scope.txt = '';
};

$scope.addNumber=function(num) { 
    $scope.txt+= num; 
    $scope.numbers.push(parseInt(num));
};

$scope.addOperator = function(operator){
   $scope.txt+= operator;
   $scope.operators.push(operator);
}

 function calc(lhs,rhs,op){
  switch(op){
    case '+':
      return lhs+ rhs;
    case '-':
      return lhs-rhs;

  }
  return 0;
}



});
```

And the view

```
<h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="calculatorCtrl">

<div class="offset4 span6 well">
<label>Enter a value :</label>
```

```
<input type="button" value="1" name="no" ng-click="addNumber('1')">  
<input type="button" value="2" name="no" ng-click="addNumber('2')">  
<input type="button" value="3" name="no" ng-click="addNumber('3')"> 
<input type="button" value="0" name="no" ng-click="addNumber('0')">  
<input type="button" value="-" name="no" ng-click="addOperator('-')">  
<input type="button" value="+" name="no" ng-click="addOperator('+')"><br>     <br>
 <button ng-click="calculate()">Calculate</button> <br><br>
 <button ng-click="numbers = []; txt=0;">Clear</button> <br><br>

 Result: {{result}}    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I not sure where is problem, but possibly you simple confusing with angular.
You already have to string associated with numbers: `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`, so on button click you simple need add button value to focused textbox model.

I change your sample, possible this snippet can help

```js
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('calculatorCtrl', function($scope) {

   function add(x, y) {
     return x + y;
   }

   function sub(x, y) {
     return x - y;
   }

   function mul(x, y) {
     return x * y;
   }

   function div(x, y) {
     return x / y;
   }

   function calc(op, x, y) {
     return $scope.operators[op](parseInt(x, 10), parseInt(y));
   }

   $scope.operators = {
     '+': add,
     '-': sub,
     '*': mul,
     '/': div
   };
   $scope.op = '+';
   $scope.calc = calc;

 });
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>

<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.0.3" data-semver="3.0.3" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<h1>Simple Calculator</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="calculatorCtrl" ng-init='isNotTBFocused=true'>

    <div class="offset4 span6 well">
      <label>Enter a value :</label>
      <input ng-model="firstNumber" type="text" ng-focus='isNotTBFocused="firstNumber"'>{{(isNotTBFocused==="firstNumber")?'!':''}}
      <br/>
      <br>


      <label>Another Value:</label>
      <input ng-model="secondNumber" type="text" ng-focus='isNotTBFocused="secondNumber"'>{{(isNotTBFocused==="secondNumber")?'!':''}}
      <br/>
      <br>

      <label>Operator:</label>{{ op }}

      <br>
      <br>
      <button ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]" ng-click='$parent[isNotTBFocused]=$parent[isNotTBFocused]+""+n' ng-disabled='isNotTBFocused===true'>{{n}}</button>
      <br>
      <button ng-repeat="(key,val) in operators" ng-click="$parent.op=key" ng-disabled='isNotTBFocused===true'>{{key}}</button>

      <button ng-click="result=calc(op,firstNumber,secondNumber)">=</button>
      <br>
      <br>Result: {{result}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late reply, but it will help new comers using **`AngularJS`**,

you can understand this with less initial knowledge in **`AngularJS`**.

[image: Simple Calculator operation using AngularJS]

and here is my simple <kbd>**Calculator**</kbd> source code snippet,

```css
<style>
        .calculator_shell{
            margin: 20px auto;
            padding: 10px;
            border: black solid 2px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 300px;
            height: 405px;
            background: lightblue;
        }
        .numfield{
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 290px;
            height: 30px;
            border: black inset 1px;
            font-family: "arial", serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            background: beige;
        }
        #result_field{
            cursor: default;
        }
        .btn {
            margin: 5px;
            width: 138px;
            height: 100px;
            font-family: "arial", serif;
            font-size: 50px;
            border: black inset 1px;
            background: lightgray;
        }
        hr {
            border: none;
            width: 290px;
            height: 1px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myCalc", []);

        app.controller("calcCtrl", function ($scope) {

            $scope.add_func = function add_func() {
                var a = Number($scope.first || 0);
                var b = Number($scope.second || 0);
                $scope.result = a+b;
            }

            $scope.subt_func = function () {
                var a = Number($scope.first || 0);
                var b = Number($scope.second || 0);
                $scope.result = a-b;
            }

            $scope.multi_func = function () {
                var a = Number($scope.first || 0);
                var b = Number($scope.second || 0);
                $scope.result = a*b;
            }

            $scope.div_func = function () {
                var a = Number($scope.first || 0);
                var b = Number($scope.second || 0);
                $scope.result = a/b;
            }

            });
    </script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myCalc" ng-controller="calcCtrl">

    <div class="calculator_shell">

        <input type="input" id="result_field" class="numfield" ng-model="result"/>
        <hr>
        <input type="input" class="numfield" ng-model="first" ng-init="first='500'"/>
        <input type="input" class="numfield" ng-model="second" ng-init="second='100'"/>

        <div>
            <input type="button" value="+" class="btn" ng-click="add_func()" />
            <input type="button" value="-" class="btn" ng-click="subt_func()" />
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="button" value="*" class="btn" ng-click="multi_func()" />
            <input type="button" value="/" class="btn" ng-click="div_func()" />
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

By running the code snippet will feel you that `CSS` part is not maintained well here, but believe me testing this source code on your local system will definitely feel you a difference.